# How to remove class name of li in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular8

Tried to remove classname of all li but not working.I do not know how to do that in angular 8.If anyone know please help to find solution.

app.component.html:

```
<tr>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="name"><span>Test 1</span></li>
    <li class="name"><span>Test 2</span></li>
    <li class="name"><span>Test 3</span></li>
    <li class="name"><span>Test 4</span></li>
    <li class="name"><span>Test 5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</tr>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 setInnertext(event){ 
    let getTr=event.target.closest('tr');
    this.renderer.removeClass(getTr.querySelector('.wrapper > ul > li'),'name'))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation when we needed trigger dynamically added class on click. For your case first target the closest tr and then iterate via querySelectorAll through its children li.

app.component.ts

```
    setInnertext($event: any) {
        $event.target.closest("ul").querySelectorAll("li").forEach(item => {
            this.renderer.removeClass(item, "name");
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps.